# How to freeze and test a list of programs?

Tags: meta-programming, testing-and-verification, hold

I have a list of problems for my students and I'm trying to use the new v10 feature `TestResults` like so:

```
solns = {233168,6857}
answers[1] = Inactivate[Total@Select[Range[3, 999], (Mod[#, 3] == 0 || Mod[#, 5] == 0) &]];
answers[2] = Inactivate[FactorInteger[600851475143][[All, 1]][[-1]]];

TestReport@Table[VerificationTest[Activate@answers[i], solns[[i]]], {i, 2}]
```

But this won't work:

[image]

I need to save the code for each solution for further study and check the timing and correctness for each and finally create a report.

Comment: `TestReport` is `HoldFirst`, so that is likely causing issues.

Comment: You are right! so how can I achieve this code freezing and testing with `TestReport`

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a good way to do this right now. In Mathematica 10.3 this will work, but until then you could move your code into a `.wlt` file (Wolfram Language Test file) and do `TestReport["filename.wlt"]`.

Comment: Why will we be forced to change the extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, I would suggest something along the lines of:

```
In[9]:= solns = {233168, 6857};
answers[1] = 
  Inactivate[
   Total@Select[
 Range[3, 999], (Mod[#, 3] == 0 || Mod[#, 5] == 0) &]];
answers[2] = Inactivate[FactorInteger[600851475143][[All, 1]][[-1]]];
#[{"Outcome", "AbsoluteTimeUsed"}] & /@ 
Table[VerificationTest[Activate@answers[i], solns[[i]]], {i, 2}]

Out[12]= {<|"Outcome" -> "Success", 
  "AbsoluteTimeUsed" -> 
   Quantity[0.001808, "Seconds"]|>, <|"Outcome" -> "Success", 
  "AbsoluteTimeUsed" -> Quantity[0.000111, "Seconds"]|>}
```